# Turn transparent png to partly transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, png

I got this .png file which is completely transparent (except for the black lines) [image: emailIcon]
How can I turn the white color inside the mail icon to non-transparent but keep the parts outside ( in the corner, because of the rounded borders) transparent?
I'm using Illustrator 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Illustrator is used for vector graphics, not raster which the PNG is.

I suggest you either edit the image in Photoshop instead or you trace the image with vectors in Illustrator and then add a white background polygon beneath the envelope outline. Export as PNG

Comment: that explains why I couldn't find the answer on google before - thanks - I'll try the tracing approach and as soon as I get it to work, I'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: If you don't have Photoshop, it's also a trivial task for ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick.

Comment: It's not quite working because after using "Object/ImageTrace/Make" it's not transparent at all anymore when I'm exporting it to PNG (even when I set "Background to Transparent there")

Comment: When tracing images you can choose if white should be transparent or a white object. Delete the white objects and you'll be fine I think.